# Wix Heat dir not accepting variable

Tags: wix, heat

"$(WiX)\bin\heat.exe" dir $(MyProject.Dir.TargetDir) -var var.MyProject.Dir.TargetDir -t "$(ProjectDir)Filter.xslt" -dr INSTALLFOLDER -cg DesktopClientOutputComponentGroup -suid -ag -scom -sreg -sfrag -srd -o "$(ProjectDir)MyProject.Dir.Output.wxs"

here dir $(MyProject.Dir.TargetDir) cannot be resolved.
How should I use it?

Answer (score 1):

How are you using this command line? Is it in an MSBuild target? Is it part of a BeforeBuild target?

If you want to use this for a build every time you build, you can use a [HarvestDirectory](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/target_reference/harvestdirectory.html) or [HarvestProject](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/target_reference/harvestprojects.html). If you are running this from MSBuild inside a proj file, you can't use $(MyProject.Dir.TargetDir) since that's the automatically generated mapping of a project's dir to a wix variable for use in the wxs source. I looked through the wix targets file and it looks like it generates all these Reference project variables using CreateProjectReferenceDefineConstants in the WixTasks.dll so you could look in there for how they do it.

I would probably just use the HarvestProject target or use a relative path to $(ProjectDir) or something like that.

You may also want to wrap your paths in quotes in case they have a space in them.

Comment: HarvestProject won't get project dependency files. Relative path is not the same in solution build and msbuild, so won't help.

Answer (score 0):

My end solution was to define project property and use it in the command

Comment: can we get some Code, please

Answer (score -1):

define Environment system variable 
MyProject=C:\CODE\TestProApp 
then command will be like 
"$(WiX)\bin\heat.exe" dir "$("$(env.MyProject)"

Ref.:
http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/votive_project_references.html